# Airpods just disappeared from settings

Tags: iphone, airpods

I updated to the latest iOS today and I heard there is a new version for Airpods also. So I paired them with the device then put them in their case.

What's interesting is that you can't check their firmware on the iPhone since they just disappear from the `general->about` menu on the iPhone.

Actually they are no where on the phone, but you can still hear music and pair them.

Not only I don't know how to update them, I also can't check their version now.

Comment: Have you tried to restart your phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Credit to 9to5Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2017/02/06/how-to-view-airpods-hardware-details-check-and-update-firmware-video/)

### To check & update the AirPod firmware, do the following:

1. Have your AirPods nearby and open the case. The normal status/connectivity window will pop up, but you can swipe that away and look at the ‘About’ screen and scroll all the way the way down.
2. On the iPhone/iPad, go to `Settings -> About`.
   [image]
3. Open the AirPods case and have them near your phone.
4. Tap the new `AirPods` section in the `About` menu.
   [image]
5. From there, you’ll be able to see detailed information about your AirPods, including the model number, serial number, and hardware version. Your info should be similar to this:

   - Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
   - Model Number: A1523
   - Firmaware Version: 3.5.1
   - Hardware Version: 1.0.0
6. If the `Firmware Version` is not **3.5.1** then you'll need to update them.  Just keep them in their case, plug them in, and next to your iPhone.  The update should happen automatically.  It might take a few hours so it's best to leave them overnight so the update can take place.